# Search for a pattern and replace it in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

Hello I have a file with multiple lines. I need to search for a pattern ("") and replace it with another one (/"") with condition that its suffix with any string.
Ex:

```
cat myfile

27;"";"firstName"";"lastName";"user1";6;"Change!1"
28;"aaa@g.com";"Pravej0001";"Khan001";"test_u_001";7;"Change!1"
```

I need to replace **firstName""** with **firstName/""** in line number one.

I have already tried below code in sed :

```
sed 's/[A-Za-z0-9]""/\/""/g' myfile
```

but it is giving output as

```
27;"";"firstNam/"";"lastName";"user1";6;"Change!1"
28;"aaa@g.com";"Pravej0001";"Khan001";"test_u_001";7;"Change!1"
```

where **e** is replaced with / . I dont want to disturb the firstName.

Expected output should be like this:

```
27;"";"firstName/"";"lastName";"user1";6;"Change!1"
28;"aaa@g.com";"Pravej0001";"Khan001";"test_u_001";7;"Change!1"
```

Any help in sed/awk/shell will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/\([A-Za-z0-9]\)""/\1\/""/g' myfile
```

or more robustly across locales:

```
sed 's/\([[:alnum:]]\)""/\1\/""/g' myfile
```

Comment: Thanks! this helps. Would be great if you have provided little explanation.

Comment: You're welcome. What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: the concept of using "1"?

Comment: You mean `\1`? That's the contents of the 1st (and only in this case) capture group (the part inside `\(...\)`.). That's a very fundamental part of sed - see the man page.